# How can I obtain a json request using a webview on android studio?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to obtain a JsonRequest from a submit on a Webview. I've seen some codes but none of them work so I am from zero so far. I know this question is repeated but, I still doesn't understand.

my html.php its

```
<?php
require_once('../Con/Conexion.php');
$username = $_POST['userName'];
$passw = $_POST['userPwd'];
       $statement=mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT idTrabajador,`Nombre del Trabajador`,`Unidades por Vender`  FROM `tablausuario` WHERE `Usuario`=? AND Contrasena=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$username,$passw);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement,$idTrabajador,$name,$uxv);
$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
$response["success"] = true;
$response["idTrabajador"] = $idTrabajador;
$response["Nombre del Trabajador"] = $name;
$response["Unidades por Vender"] = $uxv;
}
echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

I know that to call and URL Web view its

```
    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.miVisor3);
    web.setWebViewClient(new ConsultaFacturas.MyWebViewClient());
    WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl(URL_LISTA_CLIENTE);
```

But , how can I obtaint this, Json response using a webview login system

```
try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            String idTra = jsonResponse.getString("idTrabajador");
                            String naMe = jsonResponse.getString("Nombre del Trabajador");
                            String uxv = jsonResponse.getString("Unidades por Vender");
                            Intent openLog = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MenuPrincipal.class);
                            openLog.putExtra("idTrabajador", idTra);
                            openLog.putExtra("Nombre del Trabajador", naMe);
                            openLog.putExtra("Unidades por Vender", uxv);
                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(openLog);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Error de Login, Verifique su conexion o los datos ingresados")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Reintentar", null).create().show();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

***UPDATE ***

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.miVisor30);
    web.setWebViewClient(new LoginActivity.MyWebViewClient());
    WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewResultListener(), "ANDROID");**SHOWS ERROR**
    ADNROID.onResult(request.status, request.responseText);**SHOWS ERROR**
    web.loadUrl(URL_LISTA_CLIENTE);


}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

public class WebViewResultListener {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onResult(int code, String response) {
        if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                if (success) {
                    String idTra = jsonResponse.getString("idTrabajador");
                    String naMe = jsonResponse.getString("Nombre del Trabajador");
                    String uxv = jsonResponse.getString("Unidades por Vender");
                    Intent openLog = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MenuPrincipal.class);
                    openLog.putExtra("idTrabajador", idTra);
                    openLog.putExtra("Nombre del Trabajador", naMe);
                    openLog.putExtra("Unidades por Vender", uxv);
                    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(openLog);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Error de Login, Verifique su conexion o los datos ingresados")
                            .setNegativeButton("Reintentar", null).create().show();

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("WebViewResultListener", "Error code=" + code);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't read JSON response from `WebView` directly, but you can pass it from JavaScript inside `WebView` to Java using `JavascriptInterface`.

First, create `JavascriptInterface` class:

```
public static class WebViewResultListener {

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onResult(int code, String response) {
        if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
            // and so on
        } else {
            Log.e("WebViewResultListener", "Error code=" + code);
        }
    }
}
```

And add it to WebView:

```
web.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewResultListener(), "ANDROID");
```

Inside `WebView` (JavaScript) you ask user for username and password.

Inside `WebView` (JavaScript) you send these username and password to your server (PHP) and listen for result.
And when you receive the result you pass it from JavaScript to Java:

```
ADNROID.onResult(request.status, request.responseText);
```

Where *ANDROID* is a name of `JavascriptInterface` added by `addJavascriptInterface()` method.

Comment: Hello @fishbone,  i'm checking the answer you gave me , but i dont understand the part from "And add it to WebView:" till the end, as i'm new in this i'm quite lost. How do a do the "asking" process exacly? , i am updating my code bellow

Comment: Line  `ADNROID.onResult(request.status, request.responseText);` must be performed with JavaScript on your webpage displayed in `WebView.` It allows you to transfer the result of query from JavaScript to Java.
I reminds you, that all operations with the server (entering and sending username and password) should be performed in JavaScript. Method `WevView.loadUrl()` should only be used for loading your webpage with login form and JavaScript code, which will send a request to the server, get the result and transfer the result to Java.